# Automatically Port Xen Images to EC2

Tags: amazon-ec2, xen

I have a disk image that is running under Xen right now and I'd like to port it to Amazon's EC2. How can I do this in a way that is as simple as possible? I've got a script that can build the finished image from a brand new image if this helps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know of a utility to automatically port Xen images to EC2, however, you can install the EC2 tools and bundle from an AMI from there. The following is the documentation on bundling your own AMI: http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSEC2/2009-03-01/GettingStartedGuide/index.html?creating-an-image.html

Comment: Yes, that's what I was thinking would be the best way, but I wanted to see if any better ideas were out there. Thanks!